# Twitter-Bootstrap - put simple elements inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, inline

Is there anyway to put 2 `<a>` elements displaying inline?

i tryed :

```
<div class="form-inline">
<a>jjj</a>
<a>sss</a>
</div>
```

and also

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <a class="inline">jjj</a>
    <a class="inline">sss</a>
    </div>
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Anchor tags by default should be displayed `inline`. You must have some extra styling setting them to display as `block` elements or something similar.

Using your code, here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2KZVU/).

Inspect your page to find out where the anchor's `display` is being set and either modify that or set the element to `display:inline` *after* that. As you've already added `class="inline"` you can simply just add:

```
a { display:block; /* Pre-existing code */ }
a.inline {
    display:inline;
}
```

Also as a note I don't think `row-fluid` is designed to work without Bootstrap's other [scaffolding](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) elements, if you want a full-width row you should use:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <a class="inline">jjj</a>
        <a class="inline">sss</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes you are right, it was a css problem on my own stylesheet, thank you very much i'll accept your answer

Comment: But, what about twitter bootstrap?

Comment: In this context, Bootstrap and Twitter Bootstrap are the same thing.

Comment: This does not work, you can't put two elements inline that overflow the parent element. Perhaps you might want to insert more characters....